# auto cumulative calculation in a column R

Tags: r, count, autofill

I have a dataset as follows

```
 >df
  id time  cycle
  1   0    1
  1   5    NA
  2   0    1
  2   10   NA
  2   20   NA
  3   0    0
  3   2    NA
  3   5    NA
  3   8    NA
  3   15   NA
  4   0    1
  ......
```

I would like to have all `NA` auto cumulated till the next ID as this:

```
 >df.new
  id time  cycle
  1   0    1
  1   5    2
  2   0    1
  2   10   2
  2   20   3
  3   0    1
  3   2    2
  3   5    3
  3   8    4
  3   15   5
  4   0    1
  ......
```

There should be a simple way to code it in R. Please share your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df$cycle <- with(df, ave(cycle, id, FUN=seq_along))
df$cycle
 #[1] 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1
```

Or

```
sequence(tabulate(df$id)) #if IDs are in order
# [1] 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cycle = seq_along(id))

  id time cycle
1   1    0     1
2   1    5     2
3   2    0     1
4   2   10     2
5   2   20     3
6   3    0     1
7   3    2     2
8   3    5     3
9   3    8     4
10  3   15     5
11  4    0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cycle := seq_len(.N), by = id]

#     id time cycle
#  1:  1    0     1
#  2:  1    5     2
#  3:  2    0     1
#  4:  2   10     2
#  5:  2   20     3
#  6:  3    0     1
#  7:  3    2     2
#  8:  3    5     3
#  9:  3    8     4
# 10:  3   15     5
# 11:  4    0     1
```